# Does superpolynomial lower bounds of a problem in $NP$ mean that $P \neq NP$?

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np

If one proves that the lower bounds of an $NP$ problem, are not bounded by any polynomial, is this enough to prove that $P$ does not equal $NP$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
if you prove a super-polynomial lower bound on time needed to decide a
problem $\Pi \in \mathsf{NP}$, then this means that $\Pi \not\in \mathsf{P}$. Since $\Pi \in \mathsf{NP} \setminus\mathsf{P}$, the set $\mathsf{NP} \setminus\mathsf{P}$ cannot be empty, i.e., $\mathsf{P} \subset \mathsf{NP}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Unfortunately *proving* even a worse than linear lower bound is very often very difficult.